# Command "composer card import" return "Bus error"

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I try to deploy composer-rest-server on different machine with the fabric network.Then the card create is ok, but the card import returns error:

```
Bus error
```

Some say related with the environment, I have another machine (with almost the same environment) which runs composer and fabric well on it.

I tried to reconnect to the vm, change the ssh terminal, and reboot the vm, all don't work, it is a headache!
Also tried to reinstall the composer , also checked the /var/logs and the `dmesg` output, but there is no obvious clues.

So how i can determine the problem?

the env:

```
node -> v8.14.0   
composer ->0.19.18
OS -> Ubuntu16.04
It is on cloud, cpu and memory are absolutely enough.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do `./stopFabric.sh` and `./teardownFabric.sh` and delete all the network card and retry. It will Works.

Comment: but i didn't deploy the fabric network on the same machine,so i didn't start up the fabric.....